# achievement system for consecutive actions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm about to create a new competition site, where users can upload pictures/vote.

I want to add some achievement bonuses/badges based on some very easy "achievements".

Achievement examples:
Login for 5 consecutive days --
Login for 10 consecutive days --
Login for 20 consecutive days

Vote 5 pictures (not yours) --
Vote 5 pictures for 5 consecutive days

I want to be able to add more achievements without adding too much code later on. A basic rule engine will be created.

Now.. I am having some troubles trying to think out how to do it. Anyone did something similar and wants to share database structure/coding examples, or someone with a good idea for this?

Read about 50 different threads on the topic here on SO, but couldn't find anything usable.

Comment: Any table structure that you have worked out yet? Anything you've already attempted? Since achievements can be varied, they might require their specific structure. For example for consecutive thing, you'll need to keep 2 fields - one for maintaining date and another for the count. Perhaps, something like this:
1. achievement_id - identifies which achievement viz login, picture_vote etc
2. user_id - track for which user
3. last_access_date - the date on which last attempt was made for the achievement
4. count
So, the total records in this table = number of users * number of achievements

Answer (score 1):

Make a new field in the table that will contain the date of the last activity (probably name it like `lastactivity`), and then create another one and name it something like `consecutive`. After that, each time the user login (or vote), check the last activity date and if it's yesterday, increment the value of the field `consecutive` by one and update the `lastactivity` field. Otherwise, reset it to 1.